# How to select a radio button through jQuery on load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```js
$("#1").find("Radio1").prop('checked', true);
$("#2").find("Radio1").prop('checked', true);
```

```html
<div id="1" cvalue='false'>
  Are you a student  ?
  <br> <input type="radio" name="RadioB1" id="Radio1" value="1">
  <label for="Radio1">Yes</label><br>
  <input type="radio" name="RadioB1" id="Radio2" value="2">
  <label for="Radio2">No</label>
</div>
<br/>
<div id="2"  cvalue='false' >
  Do you study in a university ?
  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="RadioB1" id="Radio3" class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all" value="1">
  <label for="Radio1">Yes</label><br>
  <input type="radio" name="RadioB1" id="Radio4" class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all" value="2">
  <label for="Radio2">No</label>
</div>
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/shahid12/chcnd9tg/)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/chcnd9tg/1/

Comment: thanks , cant we have same radio button id within diffrent divs. As there are will be multiple div I will have to change the id in every div

Comment: You don't need jQuery or Javascript for this; just set your html as `<input type="radio" name="RadioB1" id="Radio1" value="1" checked>`

Answer (score 0):

First of all name for both the radio class buttons should be kept different to as to select from both the divs.

Second you are finding label and setting its prop, rather you should find the input radio buttons as:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="1"  cvalue='false'>

        Are you a student  ?

         <br> <input type="radio" name="RadioB1" id="Radio1" value="1">
          <label for="Radio1">Yes</label><br>
          <input type="radio" name="RadioB1" id="Radio2" value="2">
          <label for="Radio2">No</label>




</div>
<br/>
<div id="2"  cvalue='false' >
   Do you study in a university ?

        <br>

          <input type="radio" name="RadioB1" id="Radio3" class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all" value="1">
          <label for="Radio1">Yes</label><br>
          <input type="radio" name="RadioB1" id="Radio4" class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all" value="2">
          <label for="Radio2">No</label>



</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$('#1').find('input[name=RadioB1]').filter('#Radio1').prop('checked', true);
$('#2').find('input[name=RadioB2]').filter('#Radio3').prop('checked', true);
```

See this [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/mayank_shubham/1dsknyrz/)

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering why you want to use `javascript` to do this? you can use pure `html` like this:

```html
<div id="1" cvalue='false'>
  Are you a student  ?
  <br> <input type="radio" name="RadioB2" id="Radio1" value="1" checked="checked">
  <label for="Radio1">Yes</label><br>
  <input type="radio" name="RadioB2" id="Radio2" value="2">
  <label for="Radio2">No</label>
</div>
<br/>
<div id="2"  cvalue='false' >
  Do you study in a university ?
  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="RadioB1" id="Radio3" class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all" value="1" checked="checked">
  <label for="Radio1">Yes</label><br>
  <input type="radio" name="RadioB1" id="Radio4" class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all" value="2">
  <label for="Radio2">No</label>
</div>
```

***Note:*** All you need is to use `checked="checked"` and use different `name` to choose multiple for each question.